# Flutter BoxShadow gets pixelated on long containers at iOS

Tags: flutter

On really long boxes the shadow gets pixelated at the bottom more and more the longer the box becomes. Is there a way around this?

[image]

```
return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal: 20,
        vertical: 20,
      ),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 24),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            blurRadius: 4,
            offset: const Offset(4, 4),
            color: Theme.of(context).shadowColor.withOpacity(.25),
          ),
        ],
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
          30,
        ),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          // REALLY LONG TEXT WIDGET HERE
        ],
      )
    );
```

Setting the blur radius to some value around 40 seems to blur enough so it is not that visible anymore, but it messes up the rest of the layout.